# How do I put 3 login tries before the programs exits by itself?

Tags: java, user-interface

Whenever the user got the wrong user or password for 3 tries the program will have a pop-up message window with "You got incorrect username/password, this program will exit" then the program will exit by itself. Can you guys help me? Thank you in advance!
I tried looping with do-while, but it just pops up three logging error window.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String user = tf1.getText();
    String password = tf2.getText();

    String[] users = { "user1", "user2", "user3", "user", "JDjwa89duaJd8u&DuwADUu@A*Uj8dju" };
    String[] pass = { "pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4", "djoiaw87798duyA*(dywayd*(&d8a7D" };
    int ctr = 1;

    if (tf1.getText() != null && tf2.getText() != null) {

        if (user.equals(users[0]) && password.equals(pass[0])) {
            System.out.println("Hello: " + users[0]);
            System.out.println("Login Succesful!");
        }

        if (user.equals(users[1]) && password.equals(pass[1])) {
            System.out.println("Hello: " + users[1]);
            System.out.println("Login Succesful!");
        }

        if (user.equals(users[2]) && password.equals(pass[2])) {
            System.out.println("Hello: " + users[2]);
            System.out.println("Login Succesful!");
        }

        if (user.equals(users[3]) && password.equals(pass[3])) {
            System.out.println("Hello: " + users[3]);
            System.out.println("Login Succesful!");

        }

        if (user.equals("") && password.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type in your username/password.", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } else if (tf1.getText() != users[4] && tf2.getText() != pass[4]) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username/password", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ctr++;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm on mobile, but I'll see if I can help.

Right before you increment your counter do a check (if) to see if the user has tried < 4 (aka 3 times from 1), if so say it is incorrect. Otherwise (else), exit program with message.

As a side note, i recommend throwing the login successful in a function that loops through a key/value pair.

Check if the username exists, then check if the password with that username matches.

Comment: the function looks ok, but is repetitive so could consider using a for loop to iterate values of your arrays. Could you perhaps show the code where you are trying to implement the do-while loop and exiting?

Comment: Create a variable called `loginTries` and set it to 0. Each time a failed login attempt is made, increment it (`loginTries++;`). Also, whenever you check the password, add an if statement to see whether `loginTries > 3`, and if so, print your message and exit with `System.exit(0);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable called `loginTries` and set it to 0. Each time a failed login attempt is made, increment it (`loginTries++;`). Also, whenever you check the password, add an if statement to see whether `loginTries > 3`, and if so, print your message and exit with `System.exit(0);`
Example:

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
int loginTries = 0;
String user = tf1.getText();
String password = tf2.getText();

String[] users = {"user1", "user2", "user3", "user", "JDjwa89duaJd8u&DuwADUu@A*Uj8dju"};
String [] pass = {"pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4", "djoiaw87798duyA*(dywayd*(&d8a7D"};
int ctr = 1;

if(tf1.getText() != null && tf2.getText() != null)
{
if(loginTries > 3) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got incorrect username/password, this program will exit", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   System.exit(0);
}

     if(user.equals(users[0]) && password.equals(pass[0]))
    {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + users[0]);
        System.out.println("Login Succesful!");    
    }

   if(user.equals(users[1]) && password.equals(pass[1]))
    {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + users[1]);
        System.out.println("Login Succesful!");    
    }

    if(user.equals(users[2]) && password.equals(pass[2]))
    {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + users[2]);
        System.out.println("Login Succesful!");    
    }

    if(user.equals(users[3]) && password.equals(pass[3]))
    {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + users[3]);
        System.out.println("Login Succesful!");  
        
    }

    if (user.equals ("") && password.equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type in your username/password.", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       loginTries++;
    }      
}
 else if(tf1.getText() != users[4] && tf2.getText() != pass[4])
{

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username/password", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
 ctr++;
 loginTries++;
}

}
```

Also, instead of using additional `if`s, use `else if`.